# How to show image from FTP server in web page

Tags: html, ftp

I have ftp server with some images. I want to display those images on browser like

```
<img src="ftp://user:pass@ip_address/img.png"/>
```

Is this the right way to show the image?
Is FTP server used to show images in browsers?

I am using chrome with is blocking the image to download. I am getting error `blocked:origin` in the network request.

Can anyone help me?